# MySQL SELECT COUNT(*) From two tables based on multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have some sort of logic/sql challenge. I have two tables that hold user data and are related by a id. I would like to select the count of rows based on conditions from the two tables.

Here are my tables.

table one

```
t_contacts
id  | name    | tel     | profession | email   | sex  | city    | state   |
int | varchar | varchar | int        | varchar | char | varchar | varchar |
```

table two

```
t_contacts_meta
cid                | interest     |
int (t_contact_id) | varchar      |
```

from the table, contacts are stored on the `t_contacts` table and their interest stored on the `t_contacts_meta` table.
One contact could have multiple interests.

My issue is the SQL query.
example

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
 FROM t_contacts 
 where `state`='$state' 
    AND `profession`='$profession' 
    AND `sex`='$sex' 
    AND (
        `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_1' 
        OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_2 
        OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_n'
    )
```

The sql i provided above is not my working code its just an example. I dont even know how to go about the query.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Did you want a count of rows from `t_contacts` that meet the specified criteria, or did you want a count of rows from the `t_contacts_meta` table? (That is, if a given `t_contacts` has two matching interests, did you want that to increment the count by 1, or by 2?

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for asking that - i was a little confused as to how to put it in the question. I want a count of `t_contacts` table and i want the count to increment by 1 if a contact has any matching interest :)

Comment: Note that a JOIN operation can return more than one copy of a row from `t_contacts` (if there are multiple matching rows from `t_contacts_meta`. The `COUNT()` aggregate will count the rows returned, not just rows from `t_contacts`. (I've added an answer that demonstrates two approaches to getting a count of just the `t_contacts` rows). You should also be aware of potential SQL Injection vulnerabilities; there are coding patterns that mitigate these vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is you're probably looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(C.id) AS [count]
FROM t_contacts C
INNER JOIN t_contacts_meta M ON M.cid = C.id
                               AND M.interest IN ('interest_1', 'interest_2', 'interest_n')
WHERE C.state = 'state_value'
    AND C.profession = 'profession_value'
    AND C.sex = 'sex_value'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your answer but i get null values when i do var_dump on the result variable - what am i missing?

Comment: You replaced the values from my query? I used default values just for the sample ;-)

Comment: Yes i did replace the values with the real php values same thing. Then i removed the where clause to broaden the search result but now i get false values. It returns a value higher than expected

Comment: Plus I love your answer because i can pass the interest as a comma seperated list instead of doing multiple `OR` conditions

Comment: The `IN` clause is very useful for such kind of situation in order to avoid multiple `OR`. If you removed the `WHERE` clause it's normal that you get a higher value as expected, try to replace `COUNT(C.id)` by `*` in order to show every returned data and check if the `INNER JOIN` works correctly. I double-checked the query and i don't understand why it's not working, every conditions are well formed and the jointure is ok...

Comment: Okay i feel my issue is getting the result. How do i get the result? do i do something like `$result_var->num_rows` or simply `echo $result_var` when i echoed, i got 1 when i used num_rows i got 6 from my sample table - thanks for being so kind :)

Comment: This link may help you to test the query from your php code: [Display SQL Query Results](http://www.myguysolutions.com/2011/07/07/using-var_dump-to-display-sql-query/)

Comment: Thanks a lot man - you have saved my life :) - Sure to mention you on the code comments <3

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables first:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) as count 
FROM t_contacts c
inner join t_contacts_meta m on m.cid = c.id
where 
(c.state=$state) AND 
(c.profession=$profession) AND 
(c.sex=$sex) AND 
(m.interest=$interest_1 OR m.interest=$interest_2 OR m.interest=$interest_n)
```

Comment: It's recommended to avoid using `COUNT(*)`, the performance will be better when counting on a specified column instead of the all columns of the table.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin thanks for that tip - will keep in mind :)

Comment: @JoëlSalamin yes, my bad - I just copied it verbatim.

Comment: Another small tip for this query is to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` (see my sample query below). By using an `INNER JOIN` the result will be filtered directly during the join instead of returning every rows and then applying the `WHERE` conditions on this set of data.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a logic challenge, you need to learn how to join tables

```
SELECT count(*) as count from t_contacts as T LEFT JOIN t_contacts_meta as M ON t.id=M.id WHERE T.state='$state' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a join. Your query will work if you use the following join in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(t_contacts.id) as count FROM t_contacts LEFT JOIN t_contacts_meta ON t_contacts_meta.cid = t_contacts.id WHERE `state`='$state' AND `profession`='$profession' AND `sex`='$sex' AND (`t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_1' OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_2 OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_n')
```

I did not test this query, but you will at least get the idea, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of just rows from t_contacts, and not "count" any row from t_contacts more than once...

One approach is to use an **EXISTS** predicate with a correlated subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t_contacts t
 WHERE t.state      = 'fee'
   AND t.profession = 'fi'
   AND t.sex        = 'fo'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM t_contacts_meta m 
                 WHERE m.cid = t.id
                   AND m.interest IN ('interest_1', 'interest_2', 'interest_n')
              )
```

An alternate approach is to use a JOIN operation, and count the "distinct" rows from `t_contacts`. Assuming that the `id` column is the PRIMARY KEY of the table (or is at least guaranteed to be unique and not null.)

Note the use of the **DISTINCT** keyword inside the COUNT aggregate)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
  FROM t_contacts t
  JOIN t_contacts_meta m 
       ON m.cid = t.id
       AND m.interest IN ('interest_1', 'interest_2', 'interest_n')
 WHERE t.state      = 'fee'
   AND t.profession = 'fi'
   AND t.sex        = 'fo'
```

---

The original query appears to be including values of PHP variables in the SQL text, rather than using a prepared statement, e.g.

```
   `state`='$state'
```

Note that this pattern is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider the actual SQL text if the value of `$state` contains a single quote, or contains something carefully constructed like:

```
    a' OR 'b'='b
```

Or something more nefarious, ala [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

The normal pattern is to use the **`mysqli_real_escape_string`** function, to "escape" values included in SQL text.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer - also, i have a `$security->clean_vars()` function that handles the `mysqli_real_escape_string` :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(t_contacts_meta.interest) as count 
 FROM t_contacts_meta
 LEFT JOIN t_contacts
 ON t_contacts_meta.cid = t_contacts.id
 WHERE `t_contacts.state`='$state' 
    AND `t_contacts.profession`='$profession' 
    AND `t_contacts.sex`='$sex' 
    AND (
        `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_1' 
        OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_2 
        OR `t_contacts_meta.interest`='$interest_n'
    )
```